# Can I record us (microseconds) with AnalogBinLogger example in SdFat's library?

Tags: sd-card, time, datalogging, sd

I am using the AnalogBinLogger from the SdFat example library. I  am using it to record 8 analog channels at 5kHz! which is amazing (thank you SdFat).

Is it possible to include a separate column to provide a time-stamp in microseconds for when the samples were recorded? Or will this impair the speed at which I can log data?

Or; how reliable is the sample rate? To what degree of confidence can I assume that the sketch executes (in my case) every 200 microseconds?

I'm performing frequency analysis on the data so knowing when the data is captured or if there is any drift or skew is important to me.

Thank you in advance Arduino Crew!

...appended...
To answer @jsotola:
The sketch I am using (see below) comes with the SdFat library, which is beyond my basic understanding of code. I can write a for loop and an if statement but the stuff that goes on in this sketch is levels above where I am at right now. Trust me, if I could've I would've.

To answer @Gerben:
The 5kHz sampling rate is the default sampling rate that comes with the example sketch. As long as I can be confident that the samples are taken every 200us then I wont need the timestamp but I don't know how confident I can be or how to write a timestamp into the code.

```
/**
 * This program logs data from the Arduino ADC to a binary file.
 *
 * Samples are logged at regular intervals. Each Sample consists of the ADC
 * values for the analog pins defined in the PIN_LIST array.  The pins numbers
 * may be in any order.
 *
 * Edit the configuration constants below to set the sample pins, sample rate,
 * and other configuration values.
 *
 * If your SD card has a long write latency, it may be necessary to use
 * slower sample rates.  Using a Mega Arduino helps overcome latency
 * problems since 13 512 byte buffers will be used.
 *
 * Each 512 byte data block in the file has a four byte header followed by up
 * to 508 bytes of data. (508 values in 8-bit mode or 254 values in 10-bit mode)
 * Each block contains an integral number of samples with unused space at the
 * end of the block.
 *
 * Data is written to the file using a SD multiple block write command.
 */
#ifdef __AVR__
#include <SPI.h>
#include "SdFat.h"
#include "FreeStack.h"
#include "AnalogBinLogger.h"
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Analog pin number list for a sample.  Pins may be in any order and pin
// numbers may be repeated.
const uint8_t PIN_LIST[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Sample rate in samples per second.
const float SAMPLE_RATE = 5000;  // Must be 0.25 or greater.

// The interval between samples in seconds, SAMPLE_INTERVAL, may be set to a
// constant instead of being calculated from SAMPLE_RATE.  SAMPLE_RATE is not
// used in the code below.  For example, setting SAMPLE_INTERVAL = 2.0e-4
// will result in a 200 microsecond sample interval.
const float SAMPLE_INTERVAL = 1.0/SAMPLE_RATE;

// Setting ROUND_SAMPLE_INTERVAL non-zero will cause the sample interval to
// be rounded to a a multiple of the ADC clock period and will reduce sample
// time jitter.
#define ROUND_SAMPLE_INTERVAL 1
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ADC clock rate.
// The ADC clock rate is normally calculated from the pin count and sample
// interval.  The calculation attempts to use the lowest possible ADC clock
// rate.
//
// You can select an ADC clock rate by defining the symbol ADC_PRESCALER to
// one of these values.  You must choose an appropriate ADC clock rate for
// your sample interval.
// #define ADC_PRESCALER 7 // F_CPU/128 125 kHz on an Uno
// #define ADC_PRESCALER 6 // F_CPU/64  250 kHz on an Uno
// #define ADC_PRESCALER 5 // F_CPU/32  500 kHz on an Uno
// #define ADC_PRESCALER 4 // F_CPU/16 1000 kHz on an Uno
// #define ADC_PRESCALER 3 // F_CPU/8  2000 kHz on an Uno (8-bit mode only)
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Reference voltage.  See the processor data-sheet for reference details.
// uint8_t const ADC_REF = 0; // External Reference AREF pin.
uint8_t const ADC_REF = (1 << REFS0);  // Vcc Reference.
// uint8_t const ADC_REF = (1 << REFS1);  // Internal 1.1 (only 644 1284P Mega)
// uint8_t const ADC_REF = (1 << REFS1) | (1 << REFS0);  // Internal 1.1 or 2.56
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// File definitions.
//
// Maximum file size in blocks.
// The program creates a contiguous file with FILE_BLOCK_COUNT 512 byte blocks.
// This file is flash erased using special SD commands.  The file will be
// truncated if logging is stopped early.
const uint32_t FILE_BLOCK_COUNT = 256000;

// log file base name.  Must be six characters or less.
#define FILE_BASE_NAME "analog"

// Set RECORD_EIGHT_BITS non-zero to record only the high 8-bits of the ADC.
#define RECORD_EIGHT_BITS 0
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Pin definitions.
//
// Digital pin to indicate an error, set to -1 if not used.
// The led blinks for fatal errors. The led goes on solid for SD write
// overrun errors and logging continues.
const int8_t ERROR_LED_PIN = 3;

// SD chip select pin.
const uint8_t SD_CS_PIN = SS;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Buffer definitions.
//
// The logger will use SdFat's buffer plus BUFFER_BLOCK_COUNT additional
// buffers.  QUEUE_DIM must be a power of two larger than
//(BUFFER_BLOCK_COUNT + 1).
//
#if RAMEND < 0X8FF
#error Too little SRAM
//
#elif RAMEND < 0X10FF
// Use total of two 512 byte buffers.
const uint8_t BUFFER_BLOCK_COUNT = 1;
// Dimension for queues of 512 byte SD blocks.
const uint8_t QUEUE_DIM = 4;  // Must be a power of two!
//
#elif RAMEND < 0X20FF
// Use total of five 512 byte buffers.
const uint8_t BUFFER_BLOCK_COUNT = 4;
// Dimension for queues of 512 byte SD blocks.
const uint8_t QUEUE_DIM = 8;  // Must be a power of two!
//
#elif RAMEND < 0X40FF
// Use total of 13 512 byte buffers.
const uint8_t BUFFER_BLOCK_COUNT = 12;
// Dimension for queues of 512 byte SD blocks.
const uint8_t QUEUE_DIM = 16;  // Must be a power of two!
//
#else  // RAMEND
// Use total of 29 512 byte buffers.
const uint8_t BUFFER_BLOCK_COUNT = 28;
// Dimension for queues of 512 byte SD blocks.
const uint8_t QUEUE_DIM = 32;  // Must be a power of two!
#endif  // RAMEND
//==============================================================================
// End of configuration constants.
//==============================================================================
// Temporary log file.  Will be deleted if a reset or power failure occurs.
#define TMP_FILE_NAME "tmp_log.bin"

// Size of file base name.  Must not be larger than six.
const uint8_t BASE_NAME_SIZE = sizeof(FILE_BASE_NAME) - 1;

// Number of analog pins to log.
const uint8_t PIN_COUNT = sizeof(PIN_LIST)/sizeof(PIN_LIST[0]);

// Minimum ADC clock cycles per sample interval
const uint16_t MIN_ADC_CYCLES = 15;

// Extra cpu cycles to setup ADC with more than one pin per sample.
const uint16_t ISR_SETUP_ADC = PIN_COUNT > 1 ? 100 : 0;

// Maximum cycles for timer0 system interrupt, millis, micros.
const uint16_t ISR_TIMER0 = 160;
//==============================================================================
SdFat sd;

SdBaseFile binFile;

char binName[13] = FILE_BASE_NAME "00.bin";

#if RECORD_EIGHT_BITS
const size_t SAMPLES_PER_BLOCK = DATA_DIM8/PIN_COUNT;
typedef block8_t block_t;
#else  // RECORD_EIGHT_BITS
const size_t SAMPLES_PER_BLOCK = DATA_DIM16/PIN_COUNT;
typedef block16_t block_t;
#endif // RECORD_EIGHT_BITS

block_t* emptyQueue[QUEUE_DIM];
uint8_t emptyHead;
uint8_t emptyTail;

block_t* fullQueue[QUEUE_DIM];
volatile uint8_t fullHead;  // volatile insures non-interrupt code sees changes.
uint8_t fullTail;

// queueNext assumes QUEUE_DIM is a power of two
inline uint8_t queueNext(uint8_t ht) {
  return (ht + 1) & (QUEUE_DIM -1);
}
//==============================================================================
// Interrupt Service Routines

// Pointer to current buffer.
block_t* isrBuf;

// Need new buffer if true.
bool isrBufNeeded = true;

// overrun count
uint16_t isrOver = 0;

// ADC configuration for each pin.
uint8_t adcmux[PIN_COUNT];
uint8_t adcsra[PIN_COUNT];
uint8_t adcsrb[PIN_COUNT];
uint8_t adcindex = 1;

// Insure no timer events are missed.
volatile bool timerError = false;
volatile bool timerFlag = false;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ADC done interrupt.
ISR(ADC_vect) {
  // Read ADC data.
#if RECORD_EIGHT_BITS
  uint8_t d = ADCH;
#else  // RECORD_EIGHT_BITS
  // This will access ADCL first.
  uint16_t d = ADC;
#endif  // RECORD_EIGHT_BITS

  if (isrBufNeeded && emptyHead == emptyTail) {
    // no buffers - count overrun
    if (isrOver < 0XFFFF) {
      isrOver++;
    }

    // Avoid missed timer error.
    timerFlag = false;
    return;
  }
  // Start ADC
  if (PIN_COUNT > 1) {
    ADMUX = adcmux[adcindex];
    ADCSRB = adcsrb[adcindex];
    ADCSRA = adcsra[adcindex];
    if (adcindex == 0) {
      timerFlag = false;
    }
    adcindex =  adcindex < (PIN_COUNT - 1) ? adcindex + 1 : 0;
  } else {
    timerFlag = false;
  }
  // Check for buffer needed.
  if (isrBufNeeded) {
    // Remove buffer from empty queue.
    isrBuf = emptyQueue[emptyTail];
    emptyTail = queueNext(emptyTail);
    isrBuf->count = 0;
    isrBuf->overrun = isrOver;
    isrBufNeeded = false;
  }
  // Store ADC data.
  isrBuf->data[isrBuf->count++] = d;

  // Check for buffer full.
  if (isrBuf->count >= PIN_COUNT*SAMPLES_PER_BLOCK) {
    // Put buffer isrIn full queue.
    uint8_t tmp = fullHead;  // Avoid extra fetch of volatile fullHead.
    fullQueue[tmp] = (block_t*)isrBuf;
    fullHead = queueNext(tmp);

    // Set buffer needed and clear overruns.
    isrBufNeeded = true;
    isrOver = 0;
  }
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// timer1 interrupt to clear OCF1B
ISR(TIMER1_COMPB_vect) {
  // Make sure ADC ISR responded to timer event.
  if (timerFlag) {
    timerError = true;
  }
  timerFlag = true;
}
//==============================================================================
// Error messages stored in flash.
#define error(msg) {sd.errorPrint(F(msg));fatalBlink();}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
void fatalBlink() {
  while (true) {
    if (ERROR_LED_PIN >= 0) {
      digitalWrite(ERROR_LED_PIN, HIGH);
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(ERROR_LED_PIN, LOW);
      delay(200);
    }
  }
}
//==============================================================================
#if ADPS0 != 0 || ADPS1 != 1 || ADPS2 != 2
#error unexpected ADC prescaler bits
#endif
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// initialize ADC and timer1
void adcInit(metadata_t* meta) {
  uint8_t adps;  // prescaler bits for ADCSRA
  uint32_t ticks = F_CPU*SAMPLE_INTERVAL + 0.5;  // Sample interval cpu cycles.

  if (ADC_REF & ~((1 << REFS0) | (1 << REFS1))) {
    error("Invalid ADC reference");
  }
#ifdef ADC_PRESCALER
  if (ADC_PRESCALER > 7 || ADC_PRESCALER < 2) {
    error("Invalid ADC prescaler");
  }
  adps = ADC_PRESCALER;
#else  // ADC_PRESCALER
  // Allow extra cpu cycles to change ADC settings if more than one pin.
  int32_t adcCycles = (ticks - ISR_TIMER0)/PIN_COUNT - ISR_SETUP_ADC;

  for (adps = 7; adps > 0; adps--) {
    if (adcCycles >= (MIN_ADC_CYCLES << adps)) {
      break;
    }
  }
#endif  // ADC_PRESCALER
  meta->adcFrequency = F_CPU >> adps;
  if (meta->adcFrequency > (RECORD_EIGHT_BITS ? 2000000 : 1000000)) {
    error("Sample Rate Too High");
  }
#if ROUND_SAMPLE_INTERVAL
  // Round so interval is multiple of ADC clock.
  ticks += 1 << (adps - 1);
  ticks >>= adps;
  ticks <<= adps;
#endif  // ROUND_SAMPLE_INTERVAL

  if (PIN_COUNT > sizeof(meta->pinNumber)/sizeof(meta->pinNumber[0])) {
    error("Too many pins");
  }
  meta->pinCount = PIN_COUNT;
  meta->recordEightBits = RECORD_EIGHT_BITS;

  for (int i = 0; i < PIN_COUNT; i++) {
    uint8_t pin = PIN_LIST[i];
    if (pin >= NUM_ANALOG_INPUTS) {
      error("Invalid Analog pin number");
    }
    meta->pinNumber[i] = pin;

    // Set ADC reference and low three bits of analog pin number.
    adcmux[i] = (pin & 7) | ADC_REF;
    if (RECORD_EIGHT_BITS) {
      adcmux[i] |= 1 << ADLAR;
    }

    // If this is the first pin, trigger on timer/counter 1 compare match B.
    adcsrb[i] = i == 0 ? (1 << ADTS2) | (1 << ADTS0) : 0;
#ifdef MUX5
    if (pin > 7) {
      adcsrb[i] |= (1 << MUX5);
    }
#endif  // MUX5
    adcsra[i] = (1 << ADEN) | (1 << ADIE) | adps;
    adcsra[i] |= i == 0 ? 1 << ADATE : 1 << ADSC;
  }

  // Setup timer1
  TCCR1A = 0;
  uint8_t tshift;
  if (ticks < 0X10000) {
    // no prescale, CTC mode
    TCCR1B = (1 << WGM13) | (1 << WGM12) | (1 << CS10);
    tshift = 0;
  } else if (ticks < 0X10000*8) {
    // prescale 8, CTC mode
    TCCR1B = (1 << WGM13) | (1 << WGM12) | (1 << CS11);
    tshift = 3;
  } else if (ticks < 0X10000*64) {
    // prescale 64, CTC mode
    TCCR1B = (1 << WGM13) | (1 << WGM12) | (1 << CS11) | (1 << CS10);
    tshift = 6;
  } else if (ticks < 0X10000*256) {
    // prescale 256, CTC mode
    TCCR1B = (1 << WGM13) | (1 << WGM12) | (1 << CS12);
    tshift = 8;
  } else if (ticks < 0X10000*1024) {
    // prescale 1024, CTC mode
    TCCR1B = (1 << WGM13) | (1 << WGM12) | (1 << CS12) | (1 << CS10);
    tshift = 10;
  } else {
    error("Sample Rate Too Slow");
  }
  // divide by prescaler
  ticks >>= tshift;
  // set TOP for timer reset
  ICR1 = ticks - 1;
  // compare for ADC start
  OCR1B = 0;

  // multiply by prescaler
  ticks <<= tshift;

  // Sample interval in CPU clock ticks.
  meta->sampleInterval = ticks;
  meta->cpuFrequency = F_CPU;
  float sampleRate = (float)meta->cpuFrequency/meta->sampleInterval;
  Serial.print(F("Sample pins:"));
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < meta->pinCount; i++) {
    Serial.print(' ');
    Serial.print(meta->pinNumber[i], DEC);
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print(F("ADC bits: "));
  Serial.println(meta->recordEightBits ? 8 : 10);
  Serial.print(F("ADC clock kHz: "));
  Serial.println(meta->adcFrequency/1000);
  Serial.print(F("Sample Rate: "));
  Serial.println(sampleRate);
  Serial.print(F("Sample interval usec: "));
  Serial.println(1000000.0/sampleRate, 4);
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// enable ADC and timer1 interrupts
void adcStart() {
  // initialize ISR
  isrBufNeeded = true;
  isrOver = 0;
  adcindex = 1;

  // Clear any pending interrupt.
  ADCSRA |= 1 << ADIF;

  // Setup for first pin.
  ADMUX = adcmux[0];
  ADCSRB = adcsrb[0];
  ADCSRA = adcsra[0];

  // Enable timer1 interrupts.
  timerError = false;
  timerFlag = false;
  TCNT1 = 0;
  TIFR1 = 1 << OCF1B;
  TIMSK1 = 1 << OCIE1B;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void adcStop() {
  TIMSK1 = 0;
  ADCSRA = 0;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Convert binary file to csv file.
void binaryToCsv() {
  uint8_t lastPct = 0;
  block_t buf;
  metadata_t* pm;
  uint32_t t0 = millis();
  char csvName[13];
  StdioStream csvStream;

  if (!binFile.isOpen()) {
    Serial.println(F("No current binary file"));
    return;
  }
  binFile.rewind();
  if (binFile.read(&buf , 512) != 512) {
    error("Read metadata failed");
  }
  // Create a new csv file.
  strcpy(csvName, binName);
  strcpy(&csvName[BASE_NAME_SIZE + 3], "csv");

  if (!csvStream.fopen(csvName, "w")) {
    error("open csvStream failed");
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print(F("Writing: "));
  Serial.print(csvName);
  Serial.println(F(" - type any character to stop"));
  pm = (metadata_t*)&buf;
  csvStream.print(F("Interval,"));
  float intervalMicros = 1.0e6*pm->sampleInterval/(float)pm->cpuFrequency;
  csvStream.print(intervalMicros, 4);
  csvStream.println(F(",usec"));
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < pm->pinCount; i++) {
    if (i) {
      csvStream.putc(',');
    }
    csvStream.print(F("pin"));
    csvStream.print(pm->pinNumber[i]);
  }
  csvStream.println();
  uint32_t tPct = millis();
  while (!Serial.available() && binFile.read(&buf, 512) == 512) {
    if (buf.count == 0) {
      break;
    }
    if (buf.overrun) {
      csvStream.print(F("OVERRUN,"));
      csvStream.println(buf.overrun);
    }
    for (uint16_t j = 0; j < buf.count; j += PIN_COUNT) {
      for (uint16_t i = 0; i < PIN_COUNT; i++) {
        if (i) {
          csvStream.putc(',');
        }
        csvStream.print(buf.data[i + j]);
      }
      csvStream.println();
    }
    if ((millis() - tPct) > 1000) {
      uint8_t pct = binFile.curPosition()/(binFile.fileSize()/100);
      if (pct != lastPct) {
        tPct = millis();
        lastPct = pct;
        Serial.print(pct, DEC);
        Serial.println('%');
      }
    }
    if (Serial.available()) {
      break;
    }
  }
  csvStream.fclose();
  Serial.print(F("Done: "));
  Serial.print(0.001*(millis() - t0));
  Serial.println(F(" Seconds"));
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// read data file and check for overruns
void checkOverrun() {
  bool headerPrinted = false;
  block_t buf;
  uint32_t bgnBlock, endBlock;
  uint32_t bn = 0;

  if (!binFile.isOpen()) {
    Serial.println(F("No current binary file"));
    return;
  }
  if (!binFile.contiguousRange(&bgnBlock, &endBlock)) {
    error("contiguousRange failed");
  }
  binFile.rewind();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(F("Checking overrun errors - type any character to stop"));
  if (binFile.read(&buf , 512) != 512) {
    error("Read metadata failed");
  }
  bn++;
  while (binFile.read(&buf, 512) == 512) {
    if (buf.count == 0) {
      break;
    }
    if (buf.overrun) {
      if (!headerPrinted) {
        Serial.println();
        Serial.println(F("Overruns:"));
        Serial.println(F("fileBlockNumber,sdBlockNumber,overrunCount"));
        headerPrinted = true;
      }
      Serial.print(bn);
      Serial.print(',');
      Serial.print(bgnBlock + bn);
      Serial.print(',');
      Serial.println(buf.overrun);
    }
    bn++;
  }
  if (!headerPrinted) {
    Serial.println(F("No errors found"));
  } else {
    Serial.println(F("Done"));
  }
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// dump data file to Serial
void dumpData() {
  block_t buf;
  if (!binFile.isOpen()) {
    Serial.println(F("No current binary file"));
    return;
  }
  binFile.rewind();
  if (binFile.read(&buf , 512) != 512) {
    error("Read metadata failed");
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(F("Type any character to stop"));
  delay(1000);
  while (!Serial.available() && binFile.read(&buf , 512) == 512) {
    if (buf.count == 0) {
      break;
    }
    if (buf.overrun) {
      Serial.print(F("OVERRUN,"));
      Serial.println(buf.overrun);
    }
    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < buf.count; i++) {
      Serial.print(buf.data[i], DEC);
      if ((i+1)%PIN_COUNT) {
        Serial.print(',');
      } else {
        Serial.println();
      }
    }
  }
  Serial.println(F("Done"));
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// log data
// max number of blocks to erase per erase call
uint32_t const ERASE_SIZE = 262144L;
void logData() {
  uint32_t bgnBlock, endBlock;

  // Allocate extra buffer space.
  block_t block[BUFFER_BLOCK_COUNT];

  Serial.println();

  // Initialize ADC and timer1.
  adcInit((metadata_t*) &block[0]);

  // Find unused file name.
  if (BASE_NAME_SIZE > 6) {
    error("FILE_BASE_NAME too long");
  }
  while (sd.exists(binName)) {
    if (binName[BASE_NAME_SIZE + 1] != '9') {
      binName[BASE_NAME_SIZE + 1]++;
    } else {
      binName[BASE_NAME_SIZE + 1] = '0';
      if (binName[BASE_NAME_SIZE] == '9') {
        error("Can't create file name");
      }
      binName[BASE_NAME_SIZE]++;
    }
  }
  // Delete old tmp file.
  if (sd.exists(TMP_FILE_NAME)) {
    Serial.println(F("Deleting tmp file"));
    if (!sd.remove(TMP_FILE_NAME)) {
      error("Can't remove tmp file");
    }
  }
  // Create new file.
  Serial.println(F("Creating new file"));
  binFile.close();
  if (!binFile.createContiguous(TMP_FILE_NAME, 512 * FILE_BLOCK_COUNT)) {
    error("createContiguous failed");
  }
  // Get the address of the file on the SD.
  if (!binFile.contiguousRange(&bgnBlock, &endBlock)) {
    error("contiguousRange failed");
  }
  // Use SdFat's internal buffer.
  uint8_t* cache = (uint8_t*)sd.vol()->cacheClear();
  if (cache == 0) {
    error("cacheClear failed");
  }

  // Flash erase all data in the file.
  Serial.println(F("Erasing all data"));
  uint32_t bgnErase = bgnBlock;
  uint32_t endErase;
  while (bgnErase < endBlock) {
    endErase = bgnErase + ERASE_SIZE;
    if (endErase > endBlock) {
      endErase = endBlock;
    }
    if (!sd.card()->erase(bgnErase, endErase)) {
      error("erase failed");
    }
    bgnErase = endErase + 1;
  }
  // Start a multiple block write.
  if (!sd.card()->writeStart(bgnBlock, FILE_BLOCK_COUNT)) {
    error("writeBegin failed");
  }
  // Write metadata.
  if (!sd.card()->writeData((uint8_t*)&block[0])) {
    error("Write metadata failed");
  }
  // Initialize queues.
  emptyHead = emptyTail = 0;
  fullHead = fullTail = 0;

  // Use SdFat buffer for one block.
  emptyQueue[emptyHead] = (block_t*)cache;
  emptyHead = queueNext(emptyHead);

  // Put rest of buffers in the empty queue.
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < BUFFER_BLOCK_COUNT; i++) {
    emptyQueue[emptyHead] = &block[i];
    emptyHead = queueNext(emptyHead);
  }
  // Give SD time to prepare for big write.
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println(F("Logging - type any character to stop"));
  // Wait for Serial Idle.
  Serial.flush();
  delay(10);
  uint32_t bn = 1;
  uint32_t t0 = millis();
  uint32_t t1 = t0;
  uint32_t overruns = 0;
  uint32_t count = 0;
  uint32_t maxLatency = 0;

  // Start logging interrupts.
  adcStart();
  while (1) {
    if (fullHead != fullTail) {
      // Get address of block to write.
      block_t* pBlock = fullQueue[fullTail];

      // Write block to SD.
      uint32_t usec = micros();
      if (!sd.card()->writeData((uint8_t*)pBlock)) {
        error("write data failed");
      }
      usec = micros() - usec;
      t1 = millis();
      if (usec > maxLatency) {
        maxLatency = usec;
      }
      count += pBlock->count;

      // Add overruns and possibly light LED.
      if (pBlock->overrun) {
        overruns += pBlock->overrun;
        if (ERROR_LED_PIN >= 0) {
          digitalWrite(ERROR_LED_PIN, HIGH);
        }
      }
      // Move block to empty queue.
      emptyQueue[emptyHead] = pBlock;
      emptyHead = queueNext(emptyHead);
      fullTail = queueNext(fullTail);
      bn++;
      if (bn == FILE_BLOCK_COUNT) {
        // File full so stop ISR calls.
        adcStop();
        break;
      }
    }
    if (timerError) {
      error("Missed timer event - rate too high");
    }
    if (Serial.available()) {
      // Stop ISR calls.
      adcStop();
      if (isrBuf != 0 && isrBuf->count >= PIN_COUNT) {
        // Truncate to last complete sample.
        isrBuf->count = PIN_COUNT*(isrBuf->count/PIN_COUNT);
        // Put buffer in full queue.
        fullQueue[fullHead] = isrBuf;
        fullHead = queueNext(fullHead);
        isrBuf = 0;
      }
      if (fullHead == fullTail) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if (!sd.card()->writeStop()) {
    error("writeStop failed");
  }
  // Truncate file if recording stopped early.
  if (bn != FILE_BLOCK_COUNT) {
    Serial.println(F("Truncating file"));
    if (!binFile.truncate(512L * bn)) {
      error("Can't truncate file");
    }
  }
  if (!binFile.rename(binName)) {
    error("Can't rename file");
  }
  Serial.print(F("File renamed: "));
  Serial.println(binName);
  Serial.print(F("Max block write usec: "));
  Serial.println(maxLatency);
  Serial.print(F("Record time sec: "));
  Serial.println(0.001*(t1 - t0), 3);
  Serial.print(F("Sample count: "));
  Serial.println(count/PIN_COUNT);
  Serial.print(F("Samples/sec: "));
  Serial.println((1000.0/PIN_COUNT)*count/(t1-t0));
  Serial.print(F("Overruns: "));
  Serial.println(overruns);
  Serial.println(F("Done"));
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void setup(void) {
  if (ERROR_LED_PIN >= 0) {
    pinMode(ERROR_LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  }
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Read the first sample pin to init the ADC.
  analogRead(PIN_LIST[0]);

  Serial.print(F("FreeStack: "));
  Serial.println(FreeStack());

  // Initialize at the highest speed supported by the board that is
  // not over 50 MHz. Try a lower speed if SPI errors occur.
  if (!sd.begin(SD_CS_PIN, SD_SCK_MHZ(50))) {
    sd.initErrorPrint();
    fatalBlink();
  }
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void loop(void) {
  // Read any Serial data.
  do {
    delay(10);
  } while (Serial.available() && Serial.read() >= 0);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(F("type:"));
  Serial.println(F("c - convert file to csv"));
  Serial.println(F("d - dump data to Serial"));
  Serial.println(F("e - overrun error details"));
  Serial.println(F("r - record ADC data"));

  while(!Serial.available()) {
    SysCall::yield();
  }
  char c = tolower(Serial.read());
  if (ERROR_LED_PIN >= 0) {
    digitalWrite(ERROR_LED_PIN, LOW);
  }
  // Read any Serial data.
  do {
    delay(10);
  } while (Serial.available() && Serial.read() >= 0);

  if (c == 'c') {
    binaryToCsv();
  } else if (c == 'd') {
    dumpData();
  } else if (c == 'e') {
    checkOverrun();
  } else if (c == 'r') {
    logData();
  } else {
    Serial.println(F("Invalid entry"));
  }
}
#else  // __AVR__
#error This program is only for AVR.
#endif  // __AVR__
```

Comment: why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: How are you achieving the 5kHz? If you are using something like a timer, you should get a pretty solid 5kHz (the only drift would be the drift of the crystal). In that case not useful to add a timestamp to the data, as it would be a constant 200µs after the previous one. Though you'd have to look out for other interrupts, which can cause jitter. You also could run into problems when a SD cards write take a bit longer than usual. In that case you could lose some of your measurements. Adding a timestamp would at least enable you to detect that.